# I want the xpath to get the all the text in <strong> tag, the problem is that there is a strong within strong tag and the i want is from both strong

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy, screen-scraping

The HTML code is given below, i want all the text in `<p>` tag   including text  in both `<strong>` tags.

```
<p>
      <strong>
              <strong class="location">لاہور:&nbsp;</strong>
              پاکستانی اداکار فواد خان کا کہنا ہے کہ پاکستان اور انڈیا کے درمیان سیاسی تناؤ کا اثر ان کے بالی وڈ میں موجود افراد سے تعلقات پر بالکل نہیں پڑا لیکن موجودہ صورتحال میں ساتھ کام کرنا آسان نہیں ہے۔
      </strong>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [double backslash](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)

```py
//p//strong/text()
```

Comment: Thanks, my query got resolved, but i had to use it like
$x("//p//strong/text()").getall()      hoping this will be helpful to others.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

if I reading your question correctly you just want the text in the strong elements and not all the html

this should get the text in the first strong element

```
$x("//p/strong/text()[last()]")
```

and this should get the text in the nested strong element

```
$x("//p/strong/strong/text()")
```